# Calling Javascript on Client click event of Ajax tab panel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, tabpanel

I want to perform some check after OnClientClick event of Tab Panel in a Javascript function. If my conditions return true I want to allow tab change otherwise want to restrict user on same tab without posting back. PFB code block.

Any help will be great...

```
<cc1:TabContainer ID="tabContainer" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false"
            BackColor="Red" CssClass="ajax__tab_yuitabview-theme">
            <cc1:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="A" ID="tbPrograms" OnClientClick="ClickMe;return false">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    Tab1
                </ContentTemplate>
            </cc1:TabPanel>
            Tab2
<ContentTemplate>
                    <uc2:EmployerResources ID="B" runat="server" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </cc1:TabPanel>
            Tab3
<ContentTemplate>
                    <uc3:ExternalResources ID="C" runat="server" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </cc1:TabPanel>
        </cc1:TabContainer>
```

Comment: What platform is this? I don't see any JavaScript at all...

Comment: @tjameson: I have seperate javascript function. I thought their is no need to put that funcation as well here. It has got some logic which will either return True or False at end. It is on windows platform. ASp.Net

Answer (score 2):

Give only the name of the javascript function like tabPanel1.OnClientClick="MyJavascriptFunction" and not like this tabPanel1.OnClientClick="**MyJavascriptFunction()**"

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
onclientactivetabchanged="ClickMe;return false"
```

Answer (score 0):

add clickme function in attributes of tab panel

at the loading of page

like

```
tbPrograms.Attributes.Add("onClick","ClickMe(); return false;");
```

I hope this will work

Comment: Not much luck with this. I tried. But click function is not getting invoked